# Webserver and service discovery on iphone app

Tags: iphone, bonjour

I have implemented the cocoaHTTP server inside iphone app to breadcast its presence and discoverd by bonjour safari. I have used HTTPServer class to configure its type and port to run.

I have used following command to broadcast its presence:-
    [httpServer setType:@"_http._tcp."];

But when i change the type @"_http._tcp. to same other name like :-@"_iphone._app._IOS", then i am not able to broadcast the server and bojour could not able to see the service on safari. Is it possible to change its type? if yes how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change the type: Safari expects services of type `_http._tcp.` because that's all it can consume.

Unless your server provides some other protocol which browsers can't handle, there should be no need to change the service designation.